# Will my connections close automatically in .NET Core and EF Core or do I need to close them after executing my query?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, sqlconnection

I am new to using .NET Core and EF Core.

I have one sentence inside a table of my database and I have to execute like (using ADO.NET):

```
using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "<<my sql sentence>>";
    context.Database.OpenConnection();
    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

I found [this documentation](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql).

Is it necessary to close the connection after I execute the query? I suppose I should do it (I think), but I don't know if it is necessary, or if it will close automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to dispose the `SqlCommand` after using it and leave the rest to Entity framework or ADO.NET. SQL connections use [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling), it means the connection remains open and can be reused by a subsequent query.

Update:

The SQL connection lives in the `DbContext`, the `GetDbConnection()` [method's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getdbconnection?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_GetDbConnection_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_) says, it

> Gets the underlying ADO.NET `DbConnection` for this `DbContext`.

This means, there is one DB connection for the `DbContext`, and the connection is managed by it (including features like connection resiliency). When the DbContext is disposed, also the SQL connection is disposed.

Comment: maybe garbagecollection will dispose it right? anyway I disposed it. thx

Comment: In the database connection string you might consider setting MinPooSize and MaxPooSize to some suitable vaules, to keep consistent performance across invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add Martin answer, 
`EFCore` use a connection pool.

You can check the real count of connections in several ways.

1. `sp_who` in sql server. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
2. Add logging in ef core, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3).
3. `Perfmon` counter, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3).